# Need help "sanitizing" a custom function that pulls category slug into body class

Tags: functions, post-class, categories

Not sure if "sanitizing" is really the correct phrase to use for this but it was the best one I could think of...anyways, here is the problem:

My function works great like so...

```
// add category id to body & post classes 
function category_id_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category)
        $classes [] = $category->cat_name;
        return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'category_id_class');
add_filter('body_class', 'category_id_class');
```

That works great until the user inputs a category such as "Category 1" with a *space*. Spaces are obviously not desirable as CSS classes so if we could maybe just have a dash added to replace the space that would be perfect - just not sure how to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$category->slug` instead of `$category->cat_name`. Slugs are already lowercase and with dashes instead of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

[`sanitize_html_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_html_class) sanitizes a html classname to ensure it only contains valid characters.

```
foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category)
    $classes [] = sanitize_html_class($category->cat_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

[sanitize_title_with_dashes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes) should do the trick.

Example:

```
foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category)
    $classes [] = sanitize_title_with_dashes($category->cat_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! All i see for working examples on their reference page however is to use a specific title, mine is dynamic depending on the category so Im not too sure how to add this to my function unfortunately.

Comment: @Mr.Brown: I added an example.

Comment: Really appreciate the help AKTed, I +1'd your response since you went out of the way to show me a working example...I decided to go with pogoking answer since though since his answer was a much cleaner solution. Both are viable options though so thank you!